# Get all values of enum which contain a specific string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, enums

I have this code that finds which key the user pressed out of the values in Unity's `KeyCode` enum:

```
foreach(KeyCode kcode in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
{
  if (Input.GetKey(kcode))
  Debug.Log("KeyCode down: " + kcode);
}
```

I only want it to read number keys, which are formatted as `AlphaN` where `N` is the number on the key. To do this, I believe that I need to only get values which contain `Alpha` at the start.

How do I limit the search to only include `KeyCode` values which have `Alpha` at the beginning of their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of the keycodes you want to check.

```
private KeyCode[] numberKeys = new KeyCode[]
{
    KeyCode.Alpha0,
    KeyCode.Alpha1,
    KeyCode.Alpha2,
    KeyCode.Alpha3,
    KeyCode.Alpha4,
    KeyCode.Alpha5,
    KeyCode.Alpha6,
    KeyCode.Alpha7,
    KeyCode.Alpha8,
    KeyCode.Alpha9,
};
```

and then where you are doing the loop, use this array.

```
foreach (var keycode in numberKeys)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(keycode))
    {
        Debug.Log($"KeyCode down: {keycode}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Values from `Alpha0` to `Alpha9` form a Sequence: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html so you just need to check whether they're in the range from Alpha0 to Alpha9.

```
foreach(KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)).Cast<KeyCode>()
        .Where(kc => kc >= KeyCode.Alpha0 && kc <= KeyCode.Alpha9))
{
    if (Input.GetKey(kcode)) ...
}
```

Checking the names to start with "Alpha" will provide the same values ...

```
foreach(KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)).Cast<KeyCode>()
        .Where(kc => $"{kc:G}".StartsWith("Alpha"))
{
    if (Input.GetKey(kcode)) ...
}
```

...or using Linq

```
var kcode = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)).Cast<KeyCode>().FirstOrDefault(kc => 
    $"{kc:G}".StartsWith("Alpha") && Input.GetKey(kc));

 Debug.Log("KeyCode down: " + (kcode?.ToString() ?? "-no digit key pressed-"));
```

As of .NET 5 and higher you can replace: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)).Cast<KeyCode>()`
by `Enum.GetValues<KeyCode>()`

Comment: When I use the topmost example, I get the following error: `The non-generic method 'Enum.GetValues(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments`. Can you explain this?

Comment: Did you write: `Enum.GetValues<KeyCode>(typeof(KeyCode))` or `Enum.GetValues<KeyCode>()` the latter is correct, the first would provide the errmsg you've cited ...

Comment: Its either `Enum.GetValues<KeyCode>()` or `Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode))`. But the first is better because it returns the values as KeyCode[] not as object[].

Comment: The "better" version leads to the error. The alternative leads to a different error

Comment: It's just a standard .NET Library method. But it needs .NET (Core) 5 and higher. In .NET Framework it is unavailable. That other error is that you need to cast: 
`Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)).Cast<KeyCode>()`. I adjusted my code